# Working with dataset vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Using Visual Studio 2010

I am trying to using windows form drag and drop by datasource .

the grid generate automatically and with navigation bar with few controls like add, save , delete.

But its not work on main table , meanS When I want to add new , it show saved but its not saved in actual datatable. please help to update, insert , and delete .

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Agents_DataSet.trans' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TransTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Agents_DataSet.trans)



End Sub


Private Sub TransBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TransBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.TransBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Agents_DataSet)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Are you using Access (mdb) database or SQL Express (mdf) files as datasource for the DataSets?

Comment: Thanks for response , I am using MS Access .

Answer (score 0):

since Access doesn't support LINQ you have to type the statements on your own i think. 
 This is a snippet of an old Project where i wrote my own Querys to DB.

```
''' <summary>
''' ExecuteQuery - Execute the query and returns true the excecution was successful
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal sQuery As String) As Boolean
    Dim cConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = ConnectToAccess()
    Try
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sQuery, cConnection)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Return (True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        If cConnection IsNot Nothing Then cConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

EDIT and here the OleDb connection:

```
''' <summary>
''' ConnectToAccess - Etablish conncetion to the selected access Database
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function ConnectToAccess() As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Try
        Dim myOleDbConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        myOleDbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=access.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yourPassword;")
        myOleDbConnection.Open()
        Return myOleDbConnection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Couldnt etablish the connection to Access. ", ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: this is for MS Access and not for SQL. But the backgroung of msaccess bases on SQL. just call ExecuteQuery("update tbl_example set SomeBool=True where pkID = 1")

Comment: Thanks so much ! I got many things solved ,  but I am still stucked on insert batch record in datagridview , if you can help ... please

Comment: Dont know where exactley you stuck. but for addet rows you can do `dim dttemp as datatable = YourdataTableFromTheDatasource.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)` and then insert the rows from your dttemp.